# Publishing point cloud and building map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to publish point cloud to a topic and how to use that point cloud to build a 3D map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209123/publishing-point-cloud-and-building-map./) by [Prasun2712](https://answers.ros.org/users/22415/prasun2712/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use *stereo_image_proc* to create point cloud. (http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc)

It will also publish rectified image topics which allow you to use rtabmap_ros to create a map. (http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros)

Not sure it is what you are looking for (maybe there is also other packages to do that).

---

Originally posted by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) with karma: 379 on 2015-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0